# What is the difference between "cell.text" and "cell.textlabel.text"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
cell.text = [std objectForKey:@"name"];  
cell.textlabel.text = [std objectforkey:@"name"];
```

When I use the first option it shows a warning message: "text is deprecated".

Answer (score 7):

The deprecation warning should make it obvious what is the difference: One is the old name, the other one is the new name.

The old name is still supported for compatibility, but should not be used in new applications, as it will be removed in the future (hence the warning).